# Remove parts of layer using another image layer

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to obtain the flood water extent during a flood. I carried out a supervised classification and obtained the flood water extend, but I need to remove the part where water is everyday present (lakes, rivers etc...).
I have already an image layer with rivers etc. (taken using updateMask on a landcover image). So I need a command tool that removes from the classification output layer the part of "everyday water".

Comment: Is there a way to know, for example which pixel in the flood image is covered by water during a flood? In the same way, which pixel in the water image is covered by water?

Comment: I don't understand your questions. In principle what I need is to know the command (if present) to remove the normal water extent pixels from the flood extent.

Comment: So you have an everyday-water image where pixels representing water have value of, say 2. In the same manner, you also have a flood image where you have more pixels with value of 2 due to the flood. Now you want a third image that only shows water pixels presented in flood image but not in everyday-water image, all other pixels are masked out or assigned another value. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, It's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assume water pixels have value of 2 in both flood image and everyday image. The example code below could help:

```
flood_image = flood_image.eq(2)
everyday_image = everyday_image.eq(2)
difference_image = flood_image.subtract(everyday_image).selfMask()
```

The first two lines assign value of one to water pixels, and zero to the rest.

`difference_image` would have value of one for pixels that are water in `flood_image` but not in `everyday_image`. The rest of pixels have value of zero and are masked out with `selfMask`.

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but it's always giving me a complete empty image. I'll put here the link to my code, if you want to have a look. the subtract part stats at line 124; I've also printed the two images, so you can see all the properties. [https://code.earthengine.google.com/df57f6317293744ac396ccc831129df4]

Comment: I can see your water image is `crop` where water pixel has value of 11. But which layer is your flood image? Is it `smoother`? And water pixels in `smoother` are any unmasked pixels?

Comment: I create smoother by smoothing a classification output (var classified). I used as training set a feature collection with property called WATER, with 0 for floods and 1 for no floods. for display purposes I set the opacity of  no flood to 1 to make I transparent. I was thinking to put 0 in flood_image = flood_image.eq(2), but it didn't work.

Comment: I modified your code a little bit. The situation is not really the same as you mentioned. It should work now with `difference_image` in red colour. https://code.earthengine.google.com/7eb3697c09c53835e127125bb37954a8

Comment: Thank you very much. I started using EE a month ago and I'm pretty a noob. You saved me.

Comment: No worries. Good to know that it can help.